# Average days split by customer type

Tags: sql, average

I'm looking to generate a table that shows the average number of days between a referral and appointment, per customer type.  My SQL code looks like this at present:

```
select CustomerID, CustomerType, ReferralDate, AppointmentDate,
       Datediff(d, ReferralDate, AppointmentDate) as [Ref to App (Days)]
 From Referrals
```

The code above generates a list of the number of days from referral to appointment for each customer. What I need is a row per CustomerType (there are currently 7 customer types in my database) and then a field called [Average days from ref to app].  This will leave me with seven rows, each of which contains average number of days from referral to appointment.

I know I can use the AVG function, but I can't seem to get it to work the way I want.  The sum that I need to use will be something like this: (Total days per CustomerType)/(Total CustomerID per CustomerType) = Average days per Customer Type

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text. Also tag the dbms you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query should do what you want:

```
select r.CustomerType, 
       avg(1.0 * Datediff(day, r.ReferralDate, r.AppointmentDate)) as [Ref to App (Days)]
from Referrals r
group by r.CustomerType;
```

Basically, you just need a `group by` and to remove the extraneous columns.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff, this works perfectly!  I'm not used to using averages in SQL - I normally do them excel.  I really appreciate the assistance.